# Require a typescript module in a Javascript Node program

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code

I have a typescript library that is common to a bunch of projects in our repo.  In order to use the library, we have needed to migrate the entire project to typescript.  Then we use module-alias in our package.json, and then when node runs it picks up the .js.

module-alias requires that the consuming project be typescript, and we have a test framework written in javascript.  We would like to satisfy the following requirements:

1. Use the transpiled typescript in this project
2. Not have to run tsc manually
3. Run the debugger in vscode like we can with our typescript projects
4. We don't want to use an NPM repo because the libraries are frequently simultaneously edited.

Here's what we use for our typescript projects, but since the project is javascript, module-alias can't be used.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "",
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "module-alias": "^2.2.2",
    ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^14.14.37",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.20.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.20.0",
    "eslint": "^7.23.0",
    "eslint-plugin-no-loops": "^0.3.0",
    "typescript": "^4.2.3",
    "module-alias": "^2.2.2",
    ...
  },
  "_moduleAliases": {
    "common": "./out/common"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "es6",
      "module": "commonjs",
      "sourceMap": true,
      "outDir": "out/",
      "strict": true,
      "baseUrl": ".",
      "skipLibCheck": true,
      "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
      "noImplicitAny": true,
      "allowJs": true,
      "paths": {
          "common/*" : ["../../common/*"],
      },
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "exclude": [
      "out/",
      "node_modules/"
  ]
}
```

Comment: What's the problem? Transpiling the TS and importing it, should work fine.

Comment: Why you don’t  compile yow library?

Comment: You have provided no details of what you've tried and what has failed. SO is not a place to get people to do all your work for you. We're here to help each other when we get stuck.

Comment: I've added the package.json and tsconfig.json we are using.